# Debugging Java code line by line

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to debug code line by line in Eclipse showing which line is executing so that I understand the logic of the code? I'm new to programming, please give me suitable advice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible if you launch your program in debug mode:

[image: Eclipse Debug]

put a breakpoint in the section you want to debug.

Here is a [quick tutorial](http://www.thechiselgroup.org/node?page=4) to make a Debug launch configuration:

[image: Debug launch configuration]

Answer (score 1):

you need to:

1. create a breakpoint by double clicking the left margin of the code
2. launch your program in debug mode
3. use the stepping buttons or F5-F8 to step in different ways

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can set a breakpoint, at then step line-by-line in the debugger.

This works by running your program in debug mode (the easiest way is to launch it with the Debug button as opposed to the Run button).

In the Java source code view, you can click in the line number gutter to enable breakpoints.

When execution hits that line, the Debug perspective will open, where you can inspect (and change!) all variables, and continue execution step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes set a break point and step through the code.