# Debug mode for C in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to do this:

[Debugging Java code line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754511/debugging-java-code-line-by-line)

in eclipse for C/C++ developers?

If so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Detailed overview is provided in Eclipse's help: http://tinyurl.com/olfmbat